# call c++ exe from java

Tags: java, applet, process

I am trying to call c++ exe from java applet.For this purpose am using processbuilder.My code is as follows

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(s);
Process process = pb.start();
final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)));
pw.println(1);
pw.println(1 +"" +2);
new Thread(new Runnable() {    
   public void run() {
      try {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         String line;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
         }
      } catch (java.io.IOException e) {

      }
   }
}).start();
pw.close();
```

The c++ exe looks like this when started:

1. Find the shortest path from s to t.
2. Find the associating path from s to t within length l.
3. Find the associating path from s to t within (1+beta) times of the shortest distance from s to t.
4. Exit
   Please input the command (1-4):

once u input the command ,for example 1 we get

Please input s and t, separated by space:

After this you enter two numbers and you will get a network.

Am able to get till Please input s and t, separated by space: .After that it does not display anything.

Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
pw.println(1 +"" +2);
```

This sends the string `12`, not `1 2`.  The `""` is a zero-length string.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply.then how do i send in two numbers seperated by space?

Thanks

Comment: By printing a space between the numbers: `pw.println(1 + " " + 2);` - note the space between the quotes.

Comment: thanks.I added a space but still not getting the final output.It does not take in the arguments 1 and 2.any idea why so?

Comment: Is the C++ program reading from stdin, or directly from the console?